# Calculated crystal capacitance is out of range

Tags: capacitor, atmega, crystal

I know, another question about crystal capacitor values.

I would like to use 
[this](https://www.foxonline.com/pdfs/C4UT.pdf) crystal in the 20 MHz version to clock an ATmega1284.

According to the crystal's datasheet, it has a load capacitance of 20 pF.

Using the formula \$C = 2(C_L - C_S)\$ and assuming a stray capacitance of 2 pF or 5 pF, I get a value for each capacitor of 36 pF or 30 pF, respectively.

However, this is outside the recommended range for the capacitors of 12-22 pF according to page 46 of the ATmega1284 [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42718-ATmega1284_Datasheet.pdf).

So, can I even use this crystal, and if so, with what capacitors?

Answer (score 3):

It will *probably* work with 22pF capacitors, however the frequency will be a bit off (high). Maybe 50ppm or 75ppm, not enough to worry about the maximum frequency of the MCU.

Better to buy a part that is calibrated with a lower load capacitance.

Comment: What would happen if I used 36 pF?

Comment: Might have trouble starting when cold or hot, things like that.

Comment: If I were to use either 22 or 36 pF, which would you recommend? (This is for a hobbyist project. Not frying my chips is my main concern.)

Comment: Suggest 22pF...

Comment: It is will oscillate with either , but why choose an accurate crystal and then run it inaccurately with the wrong load capacitance. If you don't care about accuracy then why compute the capacitance in the 1st place.

Comment: As Microchip says: Care should be used in selecting values of (load capacitors). Large values increase frequency stability but decrease the loop gain and may cause oscillator start-up problems.

Answer (score 1):

They are implying you should choose a part with low load capacitance and not 20pF. This also helps reduce power consumption.

A=Series
E=10pF
G=12pF
U=13pF
L=18pF
M=20pF
N=22pF
Q=30pF
R=32pF
S=33pF